# Adobe AIR NativeProcess Hello World

Tags: air

I have

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

in my Application.xml file, but the following is producing this error:

Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.filesystem::File@619de81 to flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>New Adobe AIR Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/air/AIRAliases.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/air/AIRIntrospector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script>
function Init(){
    var myAIRFile = new air.File('C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows NT/Accessories/Wordpad.exe');
    var myProcess = new air.NativeProcess();
    var myStartup = new air.NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    myStartup.executable = myAIRFile;
    myProcess.start(myAIRFile);

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Init();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use myStartup where it belongs:

```
myProcess.start(myStartup);
```

Answer (score -4):

The code looks like an HTML code, which means that you are creating a webapp.

The nativeprocesses, are for applications on the desktop only.
Not for webappications.

Thanks
,
Neeraj

Comment: @PiotrekOkoński Why dont you explain me!

Comment: AIR apps are desktop software, not web pages. Just google AIR instead of asking.

Comment: @PiotrekOkoński I hope you understand English.Because that is exactly what I said that AIR nativeprocess is for Desktops and the code snippet shared is HTML.